# Invalid Markup error when blank page is added to a new C++/WinRT Desktop project

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp, c++-winrt

I am using the latest version of Visual Studio 2019. I made a new C++/WinRT Desktop Application project with this:

[image]

Those of you who already used this template would also be familiar with this initial source code hierarchy:

[image]

I wanted to add a new XAML file for my UI, so I tried to add a blank page with this:

[image]

[image]

However, I got Invalid Markup error saying that I cannot use builtin XAML designer with WPF project even though I have no idea about using WPF here:

[image]

How can I solve errors and make Visual Studio to show XAML layout and add UI to the project? If I make C++/WinRT **Blank App** project, The pre-included XAMLs work well on the designer. How can I make it work on C++/WinRT Desktop Application project?

Comment: If you want to host UWP controls in your desktop application, it seems that you need to use the UWP XAML hosting API. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/using-the-xaml-hosting-api).

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT So in this case, you're saying what I am thinking is not possible?

Comment: You are creating a desktop application instead of a UWP application, so it should be impossible to apply the Page from UWP.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Thanks for the reply.